# Add tenantId to route in Aurelia.js

Tags: routes, aurelia, multi-tenant

Hi I am building a multi tenant application in Aurelia framework.
When a user logs in, it will receive it's tenantId:Guid parameter too. I have put it into localStorage and aurelia container.
Now I want to have tenant routes like:

```
{ route: [ ':tenantId/users' ], name: 'users', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("administration/users/users"), nav: false, title: 'Users', layoutView: PLATFORM.moduleName("administration/shell.html") },
{ route: [ ':tenantId/groups' ], name: 'groups', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("administration/groups/groups"), nav: false, title: 'Groups', layoutView: PLATFORM.moduleName("administration/shell.html") }

etc.
```

Now how to globally set this :tenantId parameter for every route that has it. I want to do it in one place and not specify it in every  tag. Something like using Aurelia DI container to inject the session class containing the tenantId. But where and how?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to used router pipeline for this? During the pipeline, you can also get the `tenantId` and then register it globally or assign it to a global singleton so it can be accesible across component

Comment: No I haven't, do You have any link where I could take a look at this perhaps?

Comment: The doc is here http://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#pipelines
It seems you can use preActivate hook for this. Maybe have a try at that?

Comment: Also, you can use https://gist.dumber.app to do some POC and share it so folks can help you easier